Removing noise from a time series using Fourier transform
I've been told that if we have a time series, we can remove noise by taking the discrete Fourier transform of it and removing small Fourier coefficients. For example, if I start with $f:\{0, ..., N-1\} \to \mathbb{R}$, I can take $\hat{f}(m)$ and then create
$$\hat{g}(m) =
\begin{cases}
\hat{f}(m) & |\hat{f}(m)| \geq \varepsilon \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
With this, supposedly $g$ can be thought of a $f$ with noise removed. Does this work? If so, is there a general rule for selecting $\varepsilon$? In particular, anything in terms of $N$, $\|f\|_1$, and/or $\|f\|_2$?
